# Regex to find an HTML element without a particular phrase within its tags

Tags: regex, vim

I need to match `<output_channels>` elements which don't contain the phrase 'Story' between the opening `<output_channels>` and closing `</output_channels>` tags. `<output_channels>` elements are never nested, so I think I should be able to do this with regex - please don't reply that it's impossible unless it genuinely is!

Here's an example of the text I'll be searching in, using either perl or vim (I find it easier to test regexes in vim):

```
<output_channels>
  <output_channel>RSS</output_channel>
  <output_channel>Story</output_channel> 
</output_channels>

<output_channels>
  <output_channel>RSS</output_channel>
</output_channels>
```

I'm thinking I need to run something like the following, but this matches both `<output_channels>` blocks:

```
<output_channels>.*?((?!Story).)*?<\/output_channels>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of that first `.*?`.  What's happening is, after the `((?!Story).)*?` part correctly fails to match content with `Story` in it, the regex engine backtracks and gives the `.*?` a crack at it, and of course it succeeds.  Assuming, of course, that you're matching in `/s` (single-line or dot-matches-all) mode.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the message `E486: Pattern not found: <output_channels>((?!Story).)*?<\/output_channels>` . Your explanation of *why* my first guess fails is much appreciated though.

Comment: D'oh, that was trying in vim, which has different syntax. I'll try again in perl tomorrow!

Answer (score 3):

Use search term:

```
<output_channels>\_s\{-}\(\(<output_channel>\_s\{-}Story\_s\{-}<\/output_channel>\)\@!\_.\)\{-}\_s\{-}<\/output_channels>
```

This will match your 2nd `<output_channels>` element only above since it doesn't have `<output_channel>Story</output_channel>`.

`\_s` will match any white space character including new line
`\_.` will match any character including new line
`{-}` is to make a pattern *non-greedy* in vim
`\@!` is to negate preceding pattern match
`\(` and `\)` is for grouping the pattern

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that quite works. It seems to match part of the following which should be excluding on the grounds of containing the phrase 'Story':

`output_channels>
  <output_channel>RSS</output_channel>
  <output_channel>Story</output_channel>
</output_channels>`

Comment: Edited my answer to fulfill your requirement. Pls verify.

Comment: Yes that seems to work thanks. Sorry, I already accepted another answer which also worked and had a nice explanation, but I have voted your answer up.

Comment: @tog22: If the vim regex is more important to you than the the Perl regex, feel free to accept this answer instead of mine.

Comment: As an OP you have the right to mark any answer as accepted :) However I thought challenge was to do this match in vim only. It would have been pretty straight forward for me to do it in sed, perl, php, java, javascript. Also I think that php solution is just ignoring `Story`, hence `<foo>Story</foo>` is also ignored as opposed to ignoring `<output_channel>Story<\/output_channel>` as you can see here: http://ideone.com/0HYGw Yes I also think I need to attach some explanation to my answer. After spending long hours on finding above I was just too tired to write explaination which I will add now.

Answer (score 2):

This might need some adjustment depending on what your whole XML file looks like, but it works with your example:

```
<output_channels>(?:\s*<output_channel>(?!Story)[^<]+<\/output_channel>\s*)+<\/output_channels>
```

Comment: Thanks that works too, and is nice and elegant. As I said to anubhava I'm afraid I already accepted another answer which also worked and had a nice explanation, but I have voted your answer up.

Comment: @tog22: This regex only looks for the word `Story` immediately after the `<output_channel>` tag; is that valid?  It also doesn't account for words that only *start* with with `Story`, like `StoryBoard`.  Is it safe to assume you'll never see such words?  If you *do* see them, do you want to match them?